# What's the difference between Turbo Mode and Normal Mode in Marvel Vs Capcom 2?

Tags: marvel-vs-capcom-2

I'm just wondering what's the difference between these two modes in MvC 2, I'm starting to play this game. What mode should i choose for a beginner?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that Turbo Mode speeds up the gameplay, requiring you to play the game faster. For a beginner, I recommend Normal Mode as you have more time to react.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have anything to do with how fast the gameplay is because if you play a 2 player game, each player is given their own option.

The only difference I have noticed it making is if you are using a character like Chun-Li, her flurry kick is easier to do with one on ( can't remember if it's turbo or not).

Try it out and let us know.

Comment: This is wrong.  Only one player is given the option of turbo mode.  The option both players get is "easy" or "normal".  Kevin Y has the correct answer.